# Is there an R function for setting rows on aggregate data?

Tags: r, datatable, aggregate

The data I am working with is from eBird, and I am looking to sort out species occurrence by both name and year. There are over 30k individual observations, each with its own number of birds. From the raw data I posted below, on Jan 1, 2021 and someone observed 2 Cooper's Hawks, etc.

Raw looks like this:

> specificName   indivualCount   eventDate    year
> Cooper's Hawk      1              (1/1/2018)      2018
> Cooper's Hawk      1              (1/1/2020)      2020
> Cooper's Hawk      2              (1/1/2021)      2021

Ideally, I would be able to group all the Cooper's Hawks `specificName` by the `year` they were observed and sum the total `invidualcounts`. That way I can make statistical comparisons between the number of birds observed in 2018, 2019, 2020, & 2021.

I created the separate column for the year
`year <- as.POSIXct(ebird.df$eventDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y") ebird.df$year <- as.numeric(format(year, "%Y"))`

Then aggregated with the follwing: 
`aggdata <- aggregate(ebird.df$individualCount , by = list( ebird.df$specificname, ebird.df$year ), FUN = sum)`

There are hundreds of bird species, so Cooper's Hawks start on the 115th row so the output looks like this:

> Group.1   Group.2    x
> 115   2018   Cooper's Hawk    86
> 116   2019   Cooper's Hawk    152
> 117   2020   Cooper's Hawk    221
> 118   2021   Cooper's Hawk    116

My question is how to I get the data to into a table that looks like the following:

> Species Name   2018 2019 2020 2021
> Cooper's Hawk   86   152  221  116

I want to eventually run some basic ecology stats on the data using `vegan`, but one problem first I guess lol

 Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::pivot_wider()` https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in the data and code in the question so we used the code and reproducible data given in the Note at the end.

Now, using xtabs we get an xtabs table directly from ebird.df like this.  No packages are used.

```
xtabs(individualCount ~ specificName + year, ebird.df)
##                year
## specificName    2018 2020 2021
##   Cooper's Hawk    1    1    2
```

Optionally convert it to a data.frame:

```
xtabs(individualCount ~ specificName + year, ebird.df) |> 
  as.data.frame.matrix()
##               2018 2020 2021
## Cooper's Hawk    1    1    2
```

Although we did not need to use aggdata if you need it for some other reason then it can be computed using aggregate.formula like this:

```
aggregate(individualCount ~ specificName + year, ebird.df, sum)
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "specificName,individualCount,eventDate,year
\"Cooper's Hawk\",1,(1/1/2018),2018
\"Cooper's Hawk\",1,(1/1/2020),2020
\"Cooper's Hawk\",2,(1/1/2021),2021"
ebird.df <- read.csv(text = Lines, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying all day to get the data organized without having to manually sort out the raw data! This worked perfectly. I used aggregate because it was the closest I could get to compiling the data in some format. I converted to a data frame using `xtabs/as.data.frame.matrix` suggestion. Thanks so much!